# Return only specified properties from an Entity Framework class

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm pretty much brand new to Entity Framework and to ASP.NET MVC (and still learning C#), so please forgive me if some of my terminology isn't right here.

Simply, I have installed Entity Framework in my ASP.NET MVC project which I'm hoping to use to create a Web API to serve up an XML list of records. Entity Framework created my entity classes.

In my controller, I can get an XML list by using this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
{
        IEnumerable<Person> person;

        using (var context = new ContactsContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            person = context.People.ToList();
        }

        return person;
}
```

This is great.

However, what if I only want to return certain properties of the `Person` object? What if I just want, for example, the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties?

I've found examples using things like

```
person = (from p in context.People
          select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
```

But this presents problems. Doing this means that my `IEnumerable` list is no longer a list of type `Person`. If I change the type to `dynamic` it will at least compile, but the problem with that is that it doesn't display in the browser successfully, presumably because the XML deserialiser no longer knows what the structure of the object is.

Is there really no way of just returning certain properties of the object which I specify, whilst still conveying the fact that it is, in fact, a `Person` object which I'm returning? And, if not, how would I go about just returning certain properties of the object in a format which the browser can interpret as XML?

Comment: If you are only sending a subset of properties you are no longer sending the original object.  Create view models that your service returns that then can be serialized to either xml or json or whatever serialization format you choose.

Comment: So this would be a sort of 'derived class' based on the Person class? That's what I was beginning to think I needed, but I've no idea how to create one.

Comment: This would be a separate class completely independent of you domain model person.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
List<Person> persons = (from p in context.People
          select new { FName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName })
         .ToList()
         .Select(p=>new person() { FirstName= FName , LastName = LName });
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `LastName = p.LastName` should be `LName = p.LastName`? Nevertheless, this won't build - the FName and LName variables in the last line aren't recognised.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> person = context.People.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(o => new Person {
                                       FirstName = o.FirstName , 
                                       LastName = o.LastName 
                      }).ToList();
```

That way you'll be sure your list is of type Person(since if I understand that is what you need)

*Also you are declaring person as an Enumerable but you are returning a List to it

Comment: Weirdly this code still returns the XML with all the properties of the Person object, not just the FirstName and LastName.

Comment: Did you also remove the  IEnumerable<Person> person; declaration? You'd get an exception anyway but it doesn't hurt to ask. :)
Better even, replace it with the List<Person> person declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I removed that variable completely. The method is now returning type List<Person>, but I thought that was ok.